# Creating Issue using GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I am trying to create an Issue in my own `repo` using Github API, but for some reason it keeps throwing me an error

```
Route::post('/issue/create/{repo}',function ($_repo){

    $client = new Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.github.com',
        // You can set any number of default request options.
//        'timeout'  => 2.0,
    ]);
    $url = '/repos/rehan-dckap/'.$_repo.'/issues';
    // Set various headers on a request
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'query' => [
            'title' => 'IssueCreation',
            'body' => 'ThPI',
            'assignee' => '',
            'milestone' => 1,
            'labels' => [],
            'assignees' => []
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization'     => 'Bearer TOKENTOKENTOKENTOKEN'
        ]
    ]);
    return  response($response->getBody());
});
```

ERROR

Client error: `POST https://api.github.com/repos/rehan-dckap/qatouch-api-docs/issues?title=IssueCreation&body=ThPI&assignee=&milestone=1` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response: { "message": "Invalid request.\n\nFor 'links/0/schema', nil is not an object.", "documentation_url": "https://develo (truncated...)

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken quite a bit of time to try and understand what the problem is here, but without running the code itself it will be a bit tricky. Can you provide an online sandbox with that code so I can play with it? I'm happy to provide the token myself. There's two main things here.

First the `422` generally means that there was an error parsing the payload. Looking at your payload, and the error message I would try to start by removing all non-mandatory fields starting by the arrays. If we look at the error message it's saying `Nil is a not an object`. My best guesses would be problems with the arrays or the `assignee` string.

Overall my tip in these cases is to reduce the API call to the bare functional. minimum and try to isolate the problem. I would go as far as using the GitHub Example they've posted on the API page and even remove the `assignee` since it's been deprecated:

```
{
  "title": "Found a bug",
  "body": "I'm having a problem with this.",
  "milestone": 1,
  "labels": [
    "bug"
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

here you can check the error code: https://developer.github.com/v3/

```
Sending invalid fields will result in a 422 Unprocessable Entity response.

HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-Length: 149

{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Issue",
      "field": "title",
      "code": "missing_field"
    }
  ]
}
```